# Proxy Post Request to another server is failing

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am new to node.js. I have a requirement to proxy a POST request (with payload) to another server from node.js and process its response back to the browser client.

my scenario (browser <-> node.js <-> final destination server).

### This is how my code looks, before i explain my issue.

```
app.post('^*$', function(req, res) {
    delete req.headers.host; // i read somewhere to delete the old host
    req.headers.host = 'ipadress:port';
    request({ url: 'http://ipaddress:port' + req.path, headers: req.headers, body: req.body }, function(err, remoteResponse, remoteBody) {
        if (err) { return res.status(500).end('Error no response'); }
        res.writeHead(200,{
            'Content-Length': remoteBody.length,
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml' }); // copy all headers from Response
        res.end(remoteBody);
    });
});
```

---

I keep on getting "500 internal server error" "Error no response".

I strongly suspect (although not sure!) , the reason for this error is my payload from initial request is not being copied to the proxied request and the complete url which my final server expects is not there.

Can someone advise me, how i can copy the url and payload to the forwarding request ?
Also, how do i handle the response back from the forwarding serer ?
My payload is a xml object and final url is

```
http://ipaddress:port/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&senderService=BS_WSAPPS_Q&receiverParty=&receiverService=&interface=SI_OrderStatusRequest_Out&interfaceNamespace=http://xyz/IF027/EC/OrderStatus/I_WS_APPS
```

@Krzysztof Sztompka.

Here is the information you asked me to put. miine is a dev environment.

_http_outgoing.js:512
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
          ^
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:512:11)
    at Request._callback (D:\MyNode.js\serverproxy.js:18:43)
    at self.callback (D:\MyNode.js\node_modules\request\request.js:198:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Request.onRequestError (D:\MyNode.js\node_modules\request\request.js:867:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:300:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: change this : ```if (err) { return res.status(500).end('Error no response'); }``` to this: ```if (err) { return res.status(500).end(err); }``` and when you get error, there will be more details. Edit question and paste it. If it is production server change it like this: ```if (err) { console.log(err);return res.status(500).end('Error no response'); }``` and error will be in terminal

Comment: I could solve it. The issue was in request statement. Here is the correct request code , which i used

Comment: I could solve it. The issue was in request statement and authentication. var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("user id" + ":" + "password").toString("base64");
request({ url: "http://ipadress:port/",  // complete url including end point.
    method: "POST",headers: { "content-type": "text/xml",  
  "Authorization" : auth // see var declaration above.
    },
    body: soapMessage  // variable which holds XML message.
}, function (err, remoteResponse, remotebody){
    console.log(remoteResponse);
 if (err) { return res.status(500).end("error"); }
 res.writeHead(200);
 res.end(remotebody);
});